# kubernetes: how to restart pod on memory limit threshold

Tags: kubernetes

I have a deployment with memory limits

```
resources:
  limits:
    memory: 128Mi
```

But my app starts to fail when it is near to the limit, so, there is any way to restart the pod before it reaches a percentage of the memory limit?

For example if the limit is 128Mi, restart the pod when it reach 85% of it.

Comment: Hello @nivarojas. Could you share more light on your use case?`my app starts to fail when it is near to the limit` what do you mean by that? The app starts to fail when it has more memory? Please explain. If a Container exceeds its memory limit, it might be terminated. If it is restartable, the kubelet will restart it, as with any other type of runtime failure. Have you tried to adjust the limits and than observe how the app behaves?

Comment: Hello @WytrzymałyWiktor, Initially i thought that the limit was to small, so I increased the limit twise, now every pod has 1.5GB as limit, but after some time (2-3 days)  the app starts to fail after the app is near to his memory usage limit, it throws out of memory exception, I think there is a memory leak in the app. but, as use case, there is any way to prevent this kinf of errors, someting like restart the pod when a certain percentage of his memory limit is used?,

Comment: Hi again @nivarojas. Are you able to provide a full use case scenario? What is the exact memory exception error that you see? Please provide that info by editing the question.

Answer (score 5):

I am going to address this question from the Kuberentes side.

As already mentioned by arjain13, the solution you thought of is not the way to go as it is against the idea of [Requests and limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#requests-and-limits):

> If you set a memory limit of 4GiB for that Container, the kubelet (and
> container runtime) enforce the limit. The runtime prevents the
> container from using more than the configured resource limit. For
> example: when a process in the container tries to consume more than
> the allowed amount of memory, the system kernel terminates the process
> that attempted the allocation, with an out of memory (OOM) error.

You can also find an example of [Exceeding a Container's memory limit](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/#exceed-a-container-s-memory-limit):

> A Container can exceed its memory request if the Node has memory
> available. But a Container is not allowed to use more than its memory
> limit. If a Container allocates more memory than its limit, the
> Container becomes a candidate for termination. If the Container
> continues to consume memory beyond its limit, the Container is
> terminated. If a terminated Container can be restarted, the kubelet
> restarts it, as with any other type of runtime failure.

There are two things I would like to recommend you to try in your current use case:

1. Debug your application in order to eliminate the memory leak which looks like to be the source of this issue.
2. Use a [livenessProbe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes):

> Indicates whether the container is running. If the liveness probe
> fails, the kubelet kills the container, and the container is subjected
> to its restart policy.

It can be configured using the fields below:

- `initialDelaySeconds`: Number of seconds after the container has started before liveness or readiness probes are initiated. Defaults to 0 seconds. Minimum value is 0.
- `periodSeconds`: How often (in seconds) to perform the probe. Default to 10 seconds. Minimum value is 1.
- `timeoutSeconds`: Number of seconds after which the probe times out. Defaults to 1 second. Minimum value is 1.
- `successThreshold`: Minimum consecutive successes for the probe to be considered successful after having failed. Defaults to 1. Must be 1 for liveness. Minimum value is 1.
- `failureThreshold`: When a probe fails, Kubernetes will try `failureThreshold` times before giving up. Giving up in case of liveness probe means restarting the container. In case of readiness probe the Pod will be marked Unready. Defaults to 3. Minimum value is 1.

If you set the minimal values for `periodSeconds`, `timeoutSeconds`, `successThreshold` and `failureThreshold` you can expect more frequent checks and faster restarts.

Below you will find some useful sources and guides:

- [Configure Liveness, Readiness and Startup Probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/)
- [Kubernetes best practices: Resource requests and limits](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-resource-requests-and-limits)
- [Kubernetes best practices: Setting up health checks with readiness and liveness probes](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-setting-up-health-checks-with-readiness-and-liveness-probes)

Comment: Hello @Wytrzymaly Wiktor, thanks for your advice, at this time we have localized the issue with the aplication and fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that using `resources` within the pods as it defeats the purpose of `limits`. Rather you can set up the `horizontalpodautoscaler` that will spin a new pod whenever it reaches to any threshold in terms of CPU and memory..

Link to set-up the hpa can be referred [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/) with some examples [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/nodes/pods/nodes-pods-autoscaling.html)

Comment: Hello @arjain13, thanks for your advice, but in this case I think that could not help, because in this case the pod continues allowing requests and fails with out of memory exceptions. I am sure there is  memory leak in the application, but while it is been fixed I need some thing that could help to restart the pods where a certain percentage of his memory limit is used.

Comment: May be set the lower memory limit within pod then.